# simplify each expression, write the answer using positive exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

a) $\frac{(-2.5)^3}{(-2.5)^{-2}}$ (bottom is to the power of -2, for some reason the 2 is bigger!)

b) $(3^3)$$(3^{-6})$ (3 to the power of -6)

c) $\frac{s^2 t^{-1}}{(s^4t^4)^\frac{1}{2}}$ (t to the power of -1)

how do i simplify and make the exponents positive?

(i didn't have the basic requisites before in order to simplify and make exponents positive)

Comment: Do you mean $(-2.5)^{-2}$ etc.?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes

Comment: Put (-2.5)^{-2} inside dollar signs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should know that : $$a^b*a^c = a^{b+c}$$
and $$\frac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b-c}$$
So you can simplify exponents, and to write only with positive ones, it might be useful to remember that $a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$

PS : it is also important to remember that ${(a^b)}^c = a^{b*c}$ and $a^{\frac {1}{2}} = \sqrt a$

Comment: so,based on ur hints,is this right? a) -2.5$^{5}$ b) $\frac{1}{3^{3}}$ c) $\frac{s^{2}}{s^{2} t^{3}}$

Comment: That's it ! but you can simplify c) by dividing by $s^2$